# Угол внутри круга

Tags: css, css3

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажите, как внутрь круга, нарисованного на css, нарисовать уголок? Интересует именно как запихнуть его в сам круг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
:root {
  --r: 50px;
  --d: calc(var(--r) * 2);
}

.circle {
  width: var(--d); height: var(--d);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: var(--r);
  position: relative;
}

.circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: var(--r) 0 0 var(--r);
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #e056f5;
  left: var(--r);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Поддержка браузерами css-переменных, к сожалению, пока [не впечатляет](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables). Все Edge и IE идут лесом. Только в Edge 15 что-то пилят, и то не допилили.

Comment: это ж исключительно для демонстрации, чего ты так строго. тем более, прелесть кастом пропертис в том, что (как минимум в данном случае) их можно легко перевести в обычные значения.

Comment: Да я просто сказал. Я ж минус не ставил. Впрочем, плюс тоже не ставил - на мой взгляд, слишком много мест, где надо использовать значение ширины. К тому же, вообще не responsive.

Comment: ну смотри, респонсив тут достигается одной переменной, которую можно менять и в хвост, и в гриву - как и в твоём варианте. мест, где надо использовать ширину, минимально возможное, у тебя ведь эта необходимость обходится хаком с псевдоэлементом + паддингом во втором псевдоэлементе. так что это еще вопрос, где лучше, моё решение смотрит в будущее изо всех сил! :)

Comment: Да, переменную менять можно. Но лишь на абсолютные значения. Если её поменять на `30%`, то всё развалится - даже круга не будет. Я эту проблему с responsive имел в виду.

Comment: О! Я ещё способ придумал - чисто градиентный :) Правда, с полупрозрачным фоном он не сработает.

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%; /* любое значение */
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: antiquewhite;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  background: blue; /* не умеешь градиенты - залей весь сектор круга */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%); /* ну работает, но... */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, blue 50%, transparent calc(50% + 1px)); /* сгладь границу */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: плюсую за возможность использовать проценты )

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%; /* любое значение */
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, antiquewhite 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to top, antiquewhite 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, antiquewhite calc(75% + 1px))
    blue;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```